# using library(ggplot2) error in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

when i insert library(ggplot2) then it occurs error. "The application unexpectedly exited".
But it is ok on R-console.

```
 >> library(ggplot2)   // ok.
```

// server.r

```
 library(ggplot2)  # error -> "The application unexpectedly exited"
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Try to delete and reinstall the library

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem.
lib should be locate in /usr/local/lib/R/site-library.
thanks